# GPG encryption in Nautilus right click menu

Tags: files, encryption, gpg, nautilus

I often use `gpg` command to encrypt files like so

```
gpg -c file
```

which produces a `file.gpg`. I would like to get rid of the command line aspect and have a right click button in my Nautilus. I tried installing the Seahorse extension for Nautilus but it doesn't work very well and I would like to keep the simplicity of my above command. How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are two simple ways to add entries to the Nautilus context menu :

1. Nautilus scripts
2. `nautilus-actions` package, which, depending on your distribution might be depreciated.

I'm running on Debian Bullseye/sid where `nautilus-actions` is not available so I will present the way using **Nautilus script**. To learn more about this Nautilus functionality you can spend a little time on the [Ubuntu side of StackExchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nautilus-script?tab=Votes), guys talk a lot about Nautilus scripts down there. Basically, this feature allows you to add context menu entries to Bash (or Python for example) scripts located in your `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory.

---

### Using two scripts

What I propose is to implement two scripts: one to encrypt, one to decrypt. Your contextual menu will look as follows when right-clicking on a file :

[image: Nautilus right-click menu]

#### Encrypt script

The encrypt script would simply be

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Encrypt
# gpg-encrypt Nautilus script

gpg -c --no-symkey-cache "$1" && rm -f "$1"
```

where the first Bash argument `$1` is the file path selected by Nautilus when right-clicking.

The `--no-symkey-cache` prevents `gpg` from keeping the passphrase in cache. By default the passphrase is stored for a certain amount of time after encrypting and decrypting a file, I personally don't like this feature so I use this option.

I also added `&& rm -f "$1"` in order to remove the original file after encryption, you can remove that if you don't want it.

#### Decrypt script

The decrypt script would be

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Decrypt
# gpg-decrypt Nautilus script

ext=`echo "$1" | grep [.]gpg`
if [ "$ext" != "" ]; then
    gpg --batch --yes --no-symkey-cache "$1"
else
    zenity --error --text "The selected file is not crypted."
fi
```

Let me explain what the script does. It uses a variable `ext` which is empty when the selected file is not a `.gpg` file and which is *not* empty if the selected file is a `.gpg` file.

If the selected file is an encrypted `.gpg` file, the script will use the `gpg` command to decrypt it. I passed the options `--batch --yes` in order to overwrite if the output file already exists. For example decryption of `file.gpg` will overwrite `file` if it exists. If you don't want to overwrite, I suggest you use the `output` `gpg`'s option and `zenity --file-selection` to specify the decrypted file name.

If the selected file is not an encrypted `.gpg` file, the script will use `zenity --error` to pop-up an error window.

This script test whether the file is encrypted by looking through the extension. A better way to do that would be to check the MIME type of the selected file. The MIME type of the encrypted file can be found using

```bsh
$ > file
$ file -b --mime-type file.gpg
application/octet-stream
```

Since `application/octet-stream` [refers to a general binary file](http://www.mime-type.net/application/octet-stream/#) and not necessary to an encrypted file  I don't think that this approach would be better than checking on the file extension. On the other hand I know that Nautilus maps my `gpg`-encrypted files to the `application/pgp-encrypted` MIME type. Maybe someone knows how to get this MIME type from a `.gpg` file using something else than the `file` command, in that case it would be relevant.

---

### Using two files

If you don't want to use two right-click menu entries you can use one single script :

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Encrypt-Decrypt
# gpg-encrypt/decrypt Nautilus script

ext=`echo "$1" | grep [.]gpg`
if [ "$ext" != "" ]; then
    gpg --batch --yes --no-symkey-cache "$1"
else
    gpg -c --no-symkey-cache "$1" && rm -f "$1"
fi
```

This script will decrypt if the selected file is a `.gpg` file and encrypt if the selected file is every else.

---

### Decrypt with double click in Nautilus

Additionally you can allow Nautilus to decrypt encrypted `.gpg` when double-clicking by adding the following desktop entry into your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

```bsh
# Decrypt.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GPG Decrypt
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=application/pgp-encrypted;
Exec=gpg --batch --yes --no-symkey-cache %F
NoDisplay=true
```

If no other application is used by default, double-clicking in Nautilus will now decrypt the file. Seahorse might be selected as default application if you're using default GNOME, in that case you have to select `GPG Decrypt` in `Open With Other Application Menu`.

[image]

---

### Installation

This little Bash script will install everything in the right location for you :

```bsh
chmod +x 'Encrypt' 'Decrypt' # script files must be executable!
cp Encrypt Decrypt ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
cp  Decrypt.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
nautilus -q 
nautilus
```

---

### Demo

[image: Demo]

**PS:** Tested on GNOME 3.34.2 and `gpg` 2.2.17 (you can check that with `$ gpg --version`).

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of the result?

Comment: Sure no problem.

Comment: Works great for me!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt install seahorse-nautilus`

then restart Nautilus with the command:
`nautilus -q`

then right click on the file and select `Encrypt`